# SEgemenattation Error in Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, sockets

Output for code given Below is as Follow. I have coded client server program with different socket trying to make multiple connection.

While I loop for creating thread for each flow ...problem occur

Please Help !

> sudhakar@rcs-HP-xw4300-Workstation:~/Desktop$ gcc UTGen.c -o Sender -w -lpthreadsudhakar@rcs-HP-xw4300-Workstation:~/Desktop$ ./Sender -m 1 -s localhost -p 5000 -z 1024 -T 10 -P t -f 4
>
> Coonecting  for Port No 5000
>   Coonecting  for Port No 5001
>   Coonecting  for Port No 5003
>   Coonecting  for Port No 5006.
>   /Sender: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
void Start_TCP_flow()
{
    gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
    do  
       {
          n = write(sockfd,buffer,packet_size);                         
          num_pkt_send++;
          TotalSend=TotalSend+n;
        if (n < 0) 
        {
             error("ERROR writing to socket");
             exit(1);
        }
       // printf("%d Bytes Send: %d\n",num_pkt_send,n);
        gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
        memset(buffer, 0,sizeof buffer); 
    } while(1/*(tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec)<=Sen_Loop_time*/);
}

void *Send_tcp(int portno)
{   
    int port=portno;
    socketnum=port-5000;
    sockfd[socketnum]=create_tcp_socket();   
    Set_Buffer( sockfd[socketnum]);
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");

     printf(" \n Connected for Port No %d ",port); 
    int i=1;
    setsockopt(sockfd[socketnum], IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&i, sizeof(i));
    for (i=0;i<packet_size;i++)
    buffer[i]='A'; 

    printf("Started Sending Traffic for Port No %d",port);
    Start_TCP_flow();
    Sen_Loop_time=(double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 + (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec);
    close( sockfd[socketnum]);

   }
```

This is the part of Code from Main Function :

```
int i;
pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
int sockfd[NUM_THREADS];
int newsockfd[NUM_THREADS];

for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
{

     portno=portno+i;
     printf("\n Coonecting  for Port No %d",portno);        
     pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL,Send_tcp,portno);
   //  pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
}

for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);


pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Comment: Where is 'portno' initialized?  Where is declaration of 'sockfd'?

Comment: There are function written will take care of these and are working well ..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the loop index 'i' to portno in main().  This means that the 'sockfd[socketnum]=create_tcp_socket();' in one of the threads will inevitably fail as the socketnum index increases beyond the bounds of sockfd[NUM_THREADS].

Did you mean to add one rather than 'i'?

I'm rather surprised that you did not spot this during your debugging, especially with the glaring significance of the numbers:

```
Coonecting for Port No 5000;
Coonecting for Port No 5001; // Adds i which is 1
Coonecting for Port No 5003; // Adds i which is 2
Coonecting for Port No 5006; // Adds i which is 3
```